# I am trying to setup PPPoS connection using lwip on Xilinx SDK 2018.1, But i am getting an error - undefined reference to pppos_create function

Tags: c, lwip, ppp, xsdk

I have already configured zcu-102 and linux system using uart16550 scuccefully. Now i wanted to connect them through PPPoS (Point to point Protocol over serial connection) from lwip202 library. But  when i try to build my code, i get

```
undefined reference to 'pppos_create' 
undefined reference to 'ppp_connect'
```

[image: Error shown in Xsdk]

Things i have already tried:

1. Enabled Lwip202 in BSP settings.
   [image: BSP settings]
2. Enabled `PPP_SUPPORT` by changing its value from '0' to '1' in netif/ppp/ppp_opts.h
   [image: ppp_opts.h]
3. Also have included the `"ppp.h",  "pppos.h", "lwipopts.h"` in my main.c file.
   [image: main.c file]
4. Also defined `PPP_SUPPORT` as 1 in `"lwipopts.h"` as it was not there by default.
   [image: lwipopts.h]

PS: cntrl + left click on the pppos_create function does take me to the source file i.e., `pppos.h` which means that the `pppos.h` file is indeed linked to the project.

Please help..
Thanks.